# Pickling a list consisting of 'n' 2-tuple values

Tags: python, pickle, pyyaml

I want to pickle a list as it takes a long time for me to create the list. The list consists of "n" 2-tuple values where the first tuple value is a large dictionary(1k to 10k keys) and the second value is a string. N can be as large as 100s to 1000s. I would like to save such a data structure so that I may load it on convenience. If the list is human-readable it would be great, but not at the cost of performance.

I have knowledge about [Shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html), [PyYaml](http://pyyaml.org/), [cPickle](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-cPickle.html) and [JSON](https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle). I am just unsure as to what to use given my data. Initial reading on various other threads on this website and internet says that cPickle may be the best choice. Any thoughts from the gurus here?

Comment: cPickle is OK if you are staying with Python. Just be sure to use the `dump` method with the `protocol=-1` parameter. This will speed the things up.

Comment: Have you considered using a database?

Comment: Eumiro, I am staying with Python hence the decision.

Comment: Ignacio, I haven't. Is there any particular reason I should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `cPickle`, this works fine,

```
# Dummy data
from random import randint as r

a,b = 97,123

d = [(dict([(chr(r(a,b)),j) for j in range(1000)]),
       ''.join([chr(r(a,b)) for i in range(5)])) 
                            for j in range(100)]

# Pickle it
import cPickle as pickle

f = open('store.dat','w')
pickle.dump(d,f)
f.close()
```

I would also consider using something like [dumbdbm](http://docs.python.org/library/dumbdbm.html).

**Added later**

Following on from the example above, you can do something like this,

```
import dumbdbm as dbm

g = dbm.open('store.db')
g.update([(str(i),pickle.dumps(j)) for i,j in enumerate(d)])
g.close()
```

Comment: Lafrasu, Thanks for the reply. Isn't dumbdbm just for a dictionary? Can I store my data structure?

Comment: @Denzil: See the addition to the answer.

Comment: Lafrasu, Works well Thanks! Is there any particular reason dbdm is better than cPickle? I tried both and didn't make such a difference in performance atleast.

Comment: @Denzil: If you use something like dumbdbm, it's possible to access your records by key. It could make, for example, searching easier.

Comment: Lafrasu, Thanks. I wouldn't want to have any search parameters as of now. I will keep dumbdbm in mind when such a requirements comes up. Thanks!